# trouble about setting value of slider in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, slider

I have a slider in wpf and want the user , set the min and max value of it.

in xaml code :

```
     <Slider x:Name="slider1" Width="34" Minimum="{Binding Path=Minval}" Value="10"    Height="105" Margin="5,5,5,5"  Maximum="{Binding Path=Maxval}"/>

      <TextBox  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,5,5,5" Name="minvaltxt" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />

<TextBox  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,5,5,5" Name="maxvaltxt" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />

   <Button Content="Apply" Name="btn"  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" Click="btn_Click"  />
```

in code behind :

```
    private double maxval = 80;
    public double Maxval
    {

        get { return maxval; }
        set { value = maxval; }
    }

    private double minval = 5;
    public double Minval
    {

        get { return minval; }
        set { value = minval; }
    }


     private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
      minval= double.Parse(minvaltxt.Text);
      maxval= double.Parse(maxvaltxt.Text);
     slider1.Minimum = Minval
     slider1.Maximum = Maxval;

     }
```

but it does not update the min and max value of silder !
what is the problem ?
thanks for any help.

.
the question now edited.
thanks.

Comment: for starters in your xaml the max is binded to `Maxcamdistance` and in the code its called `maxval` ...

Comment: @Omribitan : hi and sorry of mistake. the question has been edited.

Comment: @Omribitan : Thanks , I found Solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of lovely users who try to help .

Finaly I found the solution.

Infact , it did not need  INotifyPropertyChanged or dependency properties !

The problem was about using 2 Windows Form Host in the same windows that causes one of

numericupdown return zero !

I do not khow why this accured but I used UserControl to overcome this problem.

User Control supports multiple Windows Form Host without any problem.

It seems that wpf windows has a limitation for hosting windows form.

Thanks alot.
Be Fresh.

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you set the `DataContext` for your view?
2. In Xaml you have used `Maxcamdistance` while the property name is `Maxval` in VM.
3. Implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your class and raise propertychanged for your property.
4. In button_click() set Properties not variables.

Comment: @ nit : Thanks , I found Solution. +1 for you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't use dependency properties or INotifyPropertyChanged to inform the UI that the values of Minval and Maxval were changed. Have a look at my answer here: [Bind boolean to visualstate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531673/bind-boolean-to-visualstate/18531876#18531876)

Comment: @ Torben_Schramme : Thanks , I found Solution. +1 for you